# Is it possible to flip two curves at the end of an animation caused by an if iteration?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, gdi+

I try to get used to, building Background animations within a VB.net Forms paint Event. To improve my search i still Need some help. With the present Information i use a VB.net Windows Form-Application. The Form has the size 300 x 300, and one timer Event.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim z As Integer = 0
Dim simpleZero As Integer = 0

Dim X As Integer = 150
Dim Y As Integer = 100
Dim rightX As Integer = 250
Dim rightY As Integer = 100

Dim sunset As Integer = 50
Dim sundawn As Integer = 100
Dim leftX As Integer = 101
Dim leftY As Integer = 100

Private Sub CurveBall(g As Graphics)
    With g
        Dim canon() As Point = {New Point(simpleZero + 150, 100), _
        New Point(simpleZero + 150, 85), _
        New Point(simpleZero + 160, 65), _
        New Point(simpleZero + 180, 50)}
        .DrawCurve(New Pen(Color.Black, 3), canon)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub DrawBall(g As Graphics)
    With g
        Dim CurvePoints() As Point = {New Point(z + 100, 100), _
        New Point(z + 130, 75), _
        New Point(z + 155, 60), _
        New Point(z + 180, 50)}
        .DrawCurve(New Pen(Color.Black, 3), CurvePoints)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Timer1.Start()
    DoubleBuffered = True
    CenterToScreen()
End Sub

Dim stepStone As Integer = 1

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If X < 150 Then
        stepStone = 1
    ElseIf X > 200 Then
        stepStone = -1
    End If
    If leftX < 100 Then
        stepStone = 1
    ElseIf leftX > 200 Then
        stepStone = -1
    End If
    If leftX < 200 Then
        z += stepStone
    End If
    If leftX < 200 Then
        simpleZero += stepStone
    End If
    X += stepStone
    leftX += stepStone
    Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Black, 3), X, Y, rightX, rightY)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Black, 3), sunset, sundawn, leftX, leftY)
    CurveBall(e.Graphics)
    DrawBall(e.Graphics)
End Sub
End Class
```

The Solution are two lines with a gap in the center, moving from a left side to a right side and back again. The center is not empty. A spike or shark flapper is in between the two lines. I want achieve that the flapper truns it`s direction at each turn the if Iteration reaches a side.
To flip the flapper i tried some matrix and Rotation Solutions, but had no success.

Answer (score 0):

An If Statement in a For Loop brought light to darkness. I can not explain the iterations. Copy and Paste the solution Code is the only way i can offer within my way. Also i have not mirrored the curve Points with a command, the Points are calculated, each seperate. It is still an original Visual Basic 2010 Form 300 x 300 with an additional timer. No other changes.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim z As Integer = 0
Dim simpleZero As Integer = 0

Dim X As Integer = 150
Dim Y As Integer = 100
Dim rightX As Integer = 250
Dim rightY As Integer = 100

Dim sunset As Integer = 50
Dim sundawn As Integer = 100
Dim leftX As Integer = 100
Dim leftY As Integer = 100

Private Sub CurveBall(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    For aNewword As Integer = 0 To -stepStone
        If X < 200 Then
            With e.Graphics
                Dim canon() As Point = {New Point(simpleZero + 150, 100), _
                New Point(simpleZero + 150, 85), _
                New Point(simpleZero + 160, 65), _
                New Point(simpleZero + 180, 50)}
                .DrawCurve(New Pen(Color.Black, 3), canon)
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub DrawBall(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    For aNewword As Integer = 0 To -stepStone
        If X < 200 Then
            With e.Graphics
                Dim CurvePoints() As Point = {New Point(z + 100, 100), _
                New Point(z + 130, 75), _
                New Point(z + 155, 60), _
                New Point(z + 180, 50)}
                .DrawCurve(New Pen(Color.Black, 3), CurvePoints)
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub stelar(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    For aNewword As Integer = 0 To stepStone
        If leftX > 100 Then
            With e.Graphics
                Dim CurvePoints() As Point = {New Point(simpleZero + 150, 100), _
                New Point(simpleZero + 114, 75), _
                New Point(simpleZero + 87, 60), _
                New Point(simpleZero + 68, 50)}
                .DrawCurve(New Pen(Color.Black, 3), CurvePoints)
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub vektor(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    For aNewword As Integer = 0 To stepStone
        If leftX > 100 Then
            With e.Graphics
                Dim CurvePoints() As Point = {New Point(z + 100, 100), _
                New Point(z + 98, 85), _
                New Point(z + 84, 65), _
                New Point(z + 68, 50)}
                .DrawCurve(New Pen(Color.Black, 3), CurvePoints)
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    CenterToScreen()
    Timer1.Start()
    DoubleBuffered = True
End Sub

Dim stepStone As Integer = 1

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If X < 150 Then
        stepStone = +1
    ElseIf X > 200 Then
        stepStone = -1
    End If
    If leftX < 100 Then
        stepStone = 1
    ElseIf leftX > 200 Then
        stepStone = -1
    End If
    If leftX < 200 Then
        z += stepStone
    End If
    If leftX < 200 Then
        simpleZero += stepStone
    End If
    X += stepStone
    leftX += stepStone
    Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Black, 3), X, Y, rightX, rightY)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Black, 3), sunset, sundawn, leftX, leftY)
    CurveBall(e)
    DrawBall(e)
    stelar(e)
    vektor(e)
End Sub
End Class
```

My Answer is not a bridge it is only a possible answer. But there are more Solutions that could be written. Shorter, but until no one provides easy Cookies i am glad to have a solution.